# Initialize Array with string in array form

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I have a string which is got from ajax result:

```
["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]
```

The string pattern is exactly as above, including `"`, and the total element is not fixed

I tried below code but doesn't work:

```
var strArr="";
$.ajax({url:"myurl",success:function(result){
     strArr=result;
}});
var arr = new Array(strArr);
```

Update: This is my latest code

```
var strArr="";
$.ajax({url:"myurl",success:function(result){
    strArr=result;
    alert(strArr); //["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]
}});
var arr= JSON.parse(strArr);
```

Comment: Set `dataType` option to `json`, then jQuery’ll parse it for you automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert that string to an actual Array, just do `JSON.parse`, like this

```
var data = '["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]';
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
# [ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5' ]
```

You can confirm the type of object returned, like this

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(JSON.parse(data)));
# [object Array]
```

Your actual code, should look something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myurl",
    success: function(result) {
        alert(JSON.parse(result));
    }
});
```

Comment: this seems works on console, but how to apply it in my above code? sorry, i'm pretty new to javascript things

Comment: @DnR `success:function(result){
var array = JSON.parse(result);
}`

Comment: do I need to include any file in my page? It seems like `JSON.parse` is not recognized

Comment: @DnR [`JSON.parse`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.2) is part of the ECMA Script specification, so no need to include anything :-)

Comment: @thefourtheye—unless the user has a pre–ES5 browser. :-) There's a [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: @RobG mmm, that is a possibility. Thanks for pointing that out :-) But there is no polyfill for that on MDN... :(

Comment: @DnR Which browser are you using?

Comment: @thefourtheye I got error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` using the same input. I'm using _Chrome V34.0.1847.131 m_

Comment: @DnR Can you please update the question with the latest code you tried?

Comment: My page is in ASP(if it does matter)

Comment: @thefourtheye—oops!! There is at [*JSON.org*](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) though.

Comment: @thefourtheye and that small changes made it! thanks.just curious, why can't I assign `result` to a string variable first?

Comment: @DnR You can, but the value will be filled in asynchronously. So the last line will not be the actual last line of code executed in your program. First, JS will send an AJAX request to the url and then it will not wait for the result. It will process the rest of the statements. So, `var arr= JSON.parse(strArr);` gets executed and by then the string variable is empty. Later on, when the response comes back for that AJAX request, the function passed to `success` will be executed.